# Error al publicar mi repositorio de GitHub

Tags: git, github, repositorio

Acabo de crear un repositorio de GitHub pero por alguna razón que no entiendo este no me quiere subir los archivos para poder publicar el repositorio.

**Este es el error que me esta lanzado por pantalla:**
[image: Error que me lanza por consola GitHub]

Comment: ¿Que ramas en tu repositorio local tienes? Tal ves tu problema sea que Github ya no permite mas ramas master, por lo que  debes crear tu rama main local y ahora si publicarla en main de tu repo de github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta donde he logrado apreciar en la captura de pantalla tu error se debe a algo tan simple como una linea de comando. Parece que has olvidado hacer el `git add .`
Prueba eliminando la carpeta **.git** de tu proyecto que siempre es la primera de arriba y prueba ir a **github** donde te muestran todos los comando que debes lanzar y una vez hecho el `git init` lanza el comando `git add .` y sigue todos los pasos como te lo muestran.

Estoy pendiente a cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un `push` primero tienes que comitear los cambios realizados. Parece al principio de la imagen que has realizado un conjunto de cambios, pero no has hecho el `commit` correspondiente. Tendrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Hacer un add y un commit de tus cambios:

```
git -am "cambios realizados xxxxxxxx"
```

2. Hacer el `push` correspondiente:

```
git push -u origin main
```